# About the optional argument in Canvas in PyS60

Tags: python, nokia, pys60

In [Python for Symbian60](http://wiki.opensource.nokia.com/projects/PyS60) blit() is defined as:

blit(image [,target=(0,0), source=((0,0),image.size), mask=None, scale=0 ])

In the optional parameter source what is the significance of image.size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that blit() will automatically use the result of `image.size` when you don't specify anything else (and thus blitting the whole image from (0,0) to (width,height)).

If you want only a smaller part of the image copied, you can use the source parameter to define a different rectangle to copy.

Answer (score 0):

Think that source=((0,0)) is the top left corner and image.size is the bottom right corner. You blit whatever is between those two points.

Similar for target, btw.